# What is the more effective count method in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question regarding the count method in a very large database.
Which one of the following is the more effective one? Do one have other possibilities to recieve the same result? Thanks for your ideas and replies.

Method 1:

```
select 
    sum(Case when customertype = 'BANK' then 1 else 0 end) as Cust_is_Bank,
    sum(Case when customertype = 'BROKER' then 1 else 0 end) as Cust_is_Broker, 
    sum(Case when customertype not in ('BANK','BROKER') then 1 else 0 end) as Cust_is_Non
from bondtrades
where 1=1;
```

Method 2:

```
select 
    customertype,
    count(customertype) 
from bondtrades
group by customertype;
```

Result of Method1:

```
Cust_is_Bank    Cust_is_Broker   Cust_is_Non

273              64              8
```

Restul of Method2:

```
Customertype  Count(Coustomertype)

 BROKER         64
 BANK           273
 OTHER          8
```

Comment: The result of the two queries is not the same, you should write the query you need, not the one which is most perfomant

Comment: These queries give different results. Both can be optimized, but with help of different methods (indexes). You are comparing apples to oranges, the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You are right, the result is not the same. But to get to count of **BANK**, **BROKER** or **OTHER** both can be used. If I need the number of all customers which are not of customertype **BANK**, which one should I use?

Comment: Check the execution plan